# An equivalent norm

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Is it possible to say that $\|u\|_{H_{0}^{2}(\Omega)}$ is equivalent to $\|\Delta u\|_{2}$?

Comment: The questions you asked so far were titled "An equivalent norm", "An inequality-Is it possible?", "An integral inequality", and "An imbedding question". Consider using more descriptive titles in the future. The column on the right titled *Related* has a few good examples of such titles.